# Apache caching with .htaccess problem (incorrect Date header?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

I am using .htaccess to cache the js / css / etc files on the website. Everything works fine, but for some reason my pages get cached, too. I looked into the headers, and it works like this:

1. Browser requests a page http://poko.lt/up
2. Server responds with 301 to http://poko.lt/up/ (with Date and Last Modified headers equal to current time)
3. Browser requests http://poko.lt/up/
4. Server responds with the page, and with Date and Last Modified headers equal to my last forced refresh (like, yesterday), but Cache-control header is fine (max-age=0)
5. I get the old version of the page :/

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|eot|ttc|ttf|otf)$">
ExpiresDefault A29030400
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

# 2 WEEKS
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A1209600
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

# NO CACHE
<FilesMatch "\/$">
ExpiresDefault A0
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

And, one can test it with the website http://poko.lt (the three red icons in the top middle of the page are the ones causing the problems). I am using FF4, and checking headers with Firebug.

Comment: A more readable way for Expiration: `ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"`. See [HTML5Boilerplate](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)

Comment: good suggestion, thanks! (no more need to convert months to seconds or minutes :))